# How to put a shadow on ag-grid fixed columns

Tags: reactjs, ag-grid

I tried to put a shadow on ag-grid fixed columns like this, but it's not doing anything:

```
.ag-pinned-left-cols-container {
  box-shadow: inset 10px 0 8px 8px rgb(0 0 0 / 15%);
}
```

How do you get a shadow onto the fixed columns, so it goes vertically along the fixed column (including the header and body)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I needed to do this as well, so that we can tell that these are pinned columns and this is how I did it :

For the columns pinned on the left side :

```
.ag-header .ag-pinned-left-header,
.ag-body-viewport .ag-pinned-left-cols-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 9px 1px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 9px 1px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

For the columns pinned on the right side :

```
.ag-header .ag-pinned-right-header,
.ag-body-viewport .ag-pinned-right-cols-container {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 1;
    -webkit-box-shadow: -9px 1px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: -9px 1px 15px -4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
```

Note : I used this with the material theme and it looks great ! it should work with all the themes except the dark ones in which you can make the color lighter.

Note 2 : I had to add the "position: relative;" and "z-index: 1;" to make it work because there are many background colors on cell and row levels and with this it should work with all settings.